# Close dropdown by clicking on specific elements on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this jumbo menu (really difficult to implement in a working fiddle so apologies for that), but I will try to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

So, now are dropdowns closing only by clicking on a dropdown next to it, but it should close when clicking anywhere in the body. So I got this partially working solution which closes the dropdown when clicking on "#navigation", but not when it's clicked on all other elements as well. How could I properly choose all other elements so the dropdown closes when clicked outside? Many thanks for all the help.

```
$(function() {
    var navItem1 = document.getElementById('navItem1');
    var navItem2 = document.getElementById('navItem2');
    var otherElements = $("body > *").not("#navigation");
    console.log(otherElements); // prints normally

    $('html').click(function (e) {
        console.log(otherElements); // prints normally
        if (e.target.id == 'navigation' || e.target == otherElements) {
        navItem1.style.display = "none";
        navItem2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        //do something
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried targeting `body` instead of `html` ?

Comment: yeah, it does the same thing..

Comment: It's kinda hard to know what's without full code example. Maybe try using codepen so we can see what is going on I think it's good when there is more code to implement.

Comment: yeah I know, but this one is really tricky to implement in a pen, would have done it if I could for sure

Comment: Try to add some console.log(test) before and inside your if statement. With this, you can check if the script is working and your condition is correct.

Comment: btw it prints the console.log(otherElements); normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to turn it around and blacklist what you aren't allowed to click to close the nav:

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    var notClickableSelector; //your currently open dropdown
    if($(event.target).closest(notClickableSelector).length === 0){
        //do something
    }
});
```

This code checks if event.target has a specific parent (notClickableSelector).
This will allow you to have a click event everywhere on the page except the currently open dropdown. Which means you can still click around in the dropdown without closing it, but have it closed if the user clicks somewhere else on the page.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you mate

Answer (score 1):

Using the html is not smart as it the parent tag of all your inner elements in the document.

What not will do is: 
***Remove elements from the set of matched elements.***
So:

```
$("body > *").not("#navigation");
```

Will remove the element containing the id attr with the value if navigation:

```
id="navigation"
```

So when you are doing:

```
if (e.target.id == 'navigation' || e.target == otherElements)
```

there is basically no navigation element to find, **you always get false**.

What you can do is use this not like this:

```
$( "input:not(:checked) + span" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
$( "input").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
```

from the jquery [documentation for not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

and the jquery [documentation for .not() method](http://api.jquery.com/not/)